# Find response times of different servers

Tags: monitoring, tivoli

I want to measure network latency between different servers in a n-tier application.

Apart from logging in the servers, is there any way I can measure the network latency between one server and another server.

We would be using ITCAM. But I am really not sure if it can help us.

Thanks.
Krishna

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a centralized network management/monitoring system with "ping probes" you can deploy on your servers. Or you could just run something simple like Munin or Nagios on all your servers with the same configuration, and harvest their results.

Answer (score 0):

Ping is always a good simple tool for P2P latency measurements. You can vary the packet count and size and measure the response time as well as the percentage packet loss. Simple, but effective.